# "Could not open the ID file" in Websphere

Tags: websphere, lotus-notes

The following code I can run without problem within Tomcat,

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String)null, (String)null, "password");
```

but in Websphere, I got exception below:

```
SystemErr     R     NotesException: Could not open the ID file
SystemErr     R     at lotus.domino.local.Session.NCreateSessionWithPasswd(Native Method)
SystemErr     R     at lotus.domino.local.Session.createSession(Unknown Source)
SystemErr     R     at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionUP(Unknown Source)
SystemErr     R     at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSession(Unknown Source)
```

It is so wired, I did check the ID file existence, at the same computer, I can also execute Lutos Notes client without problem. I really have no idea now what I can do now? Please advise.

Comment: My Notes client(8.5) is installed on a Windows7, its ID file is not located at /Program Files/..../Lotus/Notes/Data as expected, instead it is at {User}/AppData/Local/Lotus/Notes/Data, is it the reason why Websphere can't load ID file? (But Tomcat has no such problem.)

Comment: Check what OS account is WS using.

Answer (score 2):

Check the credentials under which Websphere is running.  It may not be the same as Tomcat and may not have access to the file.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I don't know much about "credentials" you mentioned, could you give more details? thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Ken is referring to the user account that the WebSphere service is running under.

Comment: Hi Ken, please see my remark above, hope it can help you investigate it, and besides I login as administrator to run Websphere. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Matt, Richard said it best.  I was referring to the WebSphere service  itself.  That process is running under a certain set of credentials.  You could run "services.msc" to view what user account is being used.  If you are running as Admin for both WebSphere and Tomcat, though, it may likely be a PATH issue as Richard suggests.

Comment: I agree with PATH issue, too. I test the same program at WindowsXP and Websphere 7, 32bit OS, ID file can be loaded without problem. But in Windows 7, I think the PATH problem is a mess, I got "program files", "program data", "user profile data" three folders, I can find NOTES.INI exists at "program data" and "user profile data" folder, I think it is the PATH issue make Lotus Notes can't find ID file. But how to solve it? I keep working on it...

Answer (score 0):

Another typical problem is that the lotus.domino classes may not be able to find the path to the notes.ini file.  The Notes client typically avoids this problem by putting the path into the command line in the desktop shortcut.  Try adding the folder containing the notes.ini file to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I also have tried to put the folder containing the notes.ini to PATH. But problem remains.

Comment: Hi Richard, please see my remark above, hope it can help you investigate it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports. You should import classes from lotus.domino package. Your problem is in using wrong classes (from lotus.domino.local packages), which require instalation of Notes client on machine where code runs. That's why it works on your Tomcat (local, I assume) and fails on deployment.

What you need is to use CORBA/DIIOP to access Domino from your code. Alter your code to get session accordingly.

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_2/

Comment: He has stated that he does have the Notes client installed, so he does not need to be using the NCSO.jar (CORBA/IIOP) classes.

Answer (score 0):

Please asign the mail id with network path like '\xxxxx\xxx\xxx.id', and make sure your service account can access the location.